# Saving Visual Studio Settings During Debug in Case of BSOD

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autosave, bsod

Is it possible to make Visual Studio save its settings (window positions, etc) at the beginning of a debug session? The project I'm currently working on has the unfortunate property of bluescreening often, and while I'd like to get to the point that we avoid bluescreens entirely, we just aren't there yet.

Often, after a bluescreen Visual Studio will forget its previous window positions and place them in rather bizarre new ones. I'm already running sync.exe before a debug session, since the BSOD's have, in the past, caused entire files to turn into pure whitespace.

So, is there a way to get VS to automatically save all its settings to disk at the beginning of a debug session?